# Reload Datatable upon return from browser tab

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a process that opens another tab to create a list of items for the user:

```
function MakeDPR(id) {
    if (!isGuid(id)) {
        ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "The value passed is not a valid GUID.", "Invalid GUID");
        return false;
    }
    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="StartDpr" target="_blank">');
    $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + id + "' />");
    $(form).append("<input type='hidden' name='programSite' value='" + programSite + "' />");
    $(body).append(form);
    form.submit().remove();
    return false;
}
```

This pops open another browser tab where the user can accept the list or cancel it.  Cancel will close the tab.  If the user accepts the list it is created and the tab is closed.  This process is started from a jQuery Datatable cell button.  Upon return the button still says "Create".  When the table is reloaded it will say "Show".  Is there any way for the original tab to know that the process was accepted and automatically reload the table?

Answer (score 0):

Why open a new tab not a modal window?

In this way you can submit the result through ajax and capture the response, then based on the response you can refresh the datatable `$('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();` and stay within the same page..

Take a look at https://jqueryui.com/dialog/